# XMLHttpRequest get request xml response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I'm trying to get the xml response from my http get request with the code above but I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">  </script>
    <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var Connect = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // Define which file to open and
  // send the request.
  Connect.open("GET", "myurl", false);
  Connect.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
  Connect.send(null);

  // Place the response in an XML document.
  var TheDocument = Connect.responseXML;
  // Place the root node in an element.
  var Customers = TheDocument.childNodes[0];

  // Retrieve each customer in turn.
  for (var i = 0; i < Customers.children.length; i++)
  {

   var Customer = Customers.children[i];
   // Access each of the data values.
   var Name = Customer.getElementsByTagName("produto_id ");
   var Age = Customer.getElementsByTagName("produto_nome");

   // Write the data to the page.
   alert(Name[0].textContent.toString());
   alert(Age[0].textContent.toString());
  }

   });
</script>
```

EDIT:
And it's the xml

```
<ListaProdutos>
<Produto>
<produto_id>1</produto_id>
<produto_codigo_barras>222222</produto_codigo_barras>
<produto_nome>PRoduto1</produto_nome>
<produto_valor>22</produto_valor>
<produto_status>A</produto_status>
<produto_descricao>aaa</produto_descricao>
<produto_user_id>1</produto_user_id>
<produto_empresa_id>1</produto_empresa_id>
</Produto>
</ListaProdutos>
```

Comment: Means `Name[0]` or `Age[0]` is undefined

Comment: but I did define in 'var Name = Customer.getElementsByTagName("produto_id ");'

Comment: It means that getElementsByTagName returned an empty nodeList and so you are trying to access an element that is not there.

Comment: pls, see my edit with the xml return

Comment: `console.log(Customers)` and `console.log(Customer)` Is it what you expect?

Comment: `("produto_id ");` there is an extra white-space

Comment: YES..is like in my edit...

Comment: nice @lastr2d2 now it works! Thx a lot all!

Answer (score 0):

What line is the error pointing to... you have an extra space, have you tried without it?

```
var Name = Customer.getElementsByTagName("produto_id");
```